# how to add jquery toggle between smarty loop or foreach items

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

For the jquery Guru's out there, I am trying. I am trying to add a jquery toggle between smarty template { foreach item list } my code works great just that it works on the first list item, it does not toggle when I click on the 2nd, 3rd etc items in the list. any suggestions?

jquery code

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#itm_add").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#itm_add_box").parent("tr").empty();
        href=$(this).attr("href");
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").empty().append('<td colspan="6"><div 
id="itm_add_box" data-href="'+href+'">
<input type="text" id="itm_serial" class="input" placeholder="Serial 
Number..." /> &nbsp; 
<input type="text" id="itm_qty" class="input" 
placeholder="Quantity..." /> &nbsp; 
<button class="green" id="itm_submit">Submit</button></div><td>');
        $("#itm_add_box button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        href2=$(this).parent("#itm_add_box").attr("data-href");
        serial=$(this).parent().find("#itm_serial").val();
            qty=$(this).parent().find("#itm_qty").val();
            href2=href2+"&item_serial="+serial+"&item_quantity="+qty;
            window.location=href2;
        });
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Smarty template:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="olohead" align="center" width="80">ID</td>
    <td class="olohead" align="center">Type</td>
    <td class="olohead" align="center">Name</td>
    <td class="olohead" align="center">No</td>
    <td class="olohead" align="center">Features</td>
                        </tr>

{foreach from=$customer item=customer}

<td class="olotd4" nowrap  align="center">{$customer.ID}</td>
<td class="olotd4" nowrap align="center">{$customer.TYPE}</td>
    <td class="olotd4" nowrap >&nbsp;{$customer.NAME} </td>
    <td class="olotd4" nowrap >&nbsp;{$customer.NO} </td>
    <td class="olotd4" nowrap align="center">

<a id="itm_add">Add</a>

</td>                               
</tr>

{/foreach}
</table>
```

Again: This works, just that the toggle only works on the first listed item. Any suggestions?

Comment: `id="itm_add"`is inside your loop. This will produce double id's which is invalid HTML and make your JS act weird as it does. Use a class in stead!

Comment: Thanks PeterVR. class did the trick. this is also opening multiple rows, how can I enable only 1 to display, something like closing the old instance {class}. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to remove the `id` from the loop and make it into a class was already made in the comments. With that in mind, I tried to clean up your js a bit:

```
$(function() {
    $(".itm_add").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent("tr").empty();
        $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").empty().append(getTemplate($(this).attr("href")));
        $(this).find("button").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).parent("#itm_add_box").attr("data-href");
            var serial = $(this).parent().find("#itm_serial").val();
            var qty = $(this).parent().find("#itm_qty").val();
            href += "&item_serial=" + serial + "&item_quantity=" + qty;
            window.location = href;
        });
    });
});



function getTemplate(href) {
    return '<td colspan="6">'
                + '<div id="itm_add_box" data-href="' + href + '" >'
                    + '<input type="text" id="itm_serial" class="input" placeholder="Serial Number..." /> &nbsp;'
                    + '<input type="text" id="itm_qty" class="input" placeholder="Quantity..." /> &nbsp;'
                    + '<button class="green" id="itm_submit">Submit</button>'+
                +'</div>' 
         + '<td>';
}
```

Note that this code is not tested, so there could be bugs in there...

What I changed:

- Removed the `.each`as it is not required. jQuery will automatically
  add the event handler on all elements that the selector applies to.
- Used `$(this)` inside the handler, to make the code only apply to the item that has triggered the event, in stead of all the matched items.
- Moved the html to a separate function, just to keep things a bit more readable.
- Made all the variables function scope in stead of global, by adding the `var`keyword in front of their declaration.

Let me know if there are any bugs that I missed, or if this is anything that needs further explanation.

Comment: Hi peterVR, thank you for your time and erffort in this, I really appreciate it. it works fine just that it does not auto close the old class. when I click on each item it shows the inputs but I would like it to remove the old class when a new one is triggered. any other suggestions? thanks once again :)

Comment: hi peter, I just tested the code, seems to have some issues. it is not submitting and it puts NaN after the submit button